# Does WaitForMultipleObjects() reset all auto-reset events?

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi, events, asynchronous

I've got an event loop that's waiting on several auto-reset events.
The events were all initialized into array `eventHandles_` with `CreateEvent(NULL, false, false, NULL)`.

```
while (true)
{
    DWORD waitResult = WaitForMultipleObjects(3, eventHandles_, false, INFINITE);
    switch (waitResult)
    {
    case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 0:
        //handle event...

    case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1:
        //handle event...

    case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 2:
        //handle event...
    }
}
```

My question: if event 1 and 2 occur simultaneously, the loop will process `WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1` because it's first.  But will event 2 remain signaled when the loop comes around again?  Or does it get reset automatically?

Comment: In general, it's just best to try to avoid such constructs.  I would have each signaling thread push a suitable index, delegate or whatever onto a thread-safe queue and signal a single semaphore.  This designs around the issue - the behaviour is entirely known and predictable, no events will ever get lost even if one thread signals more than once, there is no 64-handle restriction and the number of signaling theads is not fixed at compile time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"...modification occurs only for the object or objects whose signaled state caused the function to return..."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025(v=vs.85).aspx

And from the mouth of one [Raymond Chen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22814435/will-waitformultipleobjects-modify-the-state-of-multiple-objects/22819089#comment34794743_22814435):

> If waiting for one event, then only that event is modified. If waiting
>   for all events, then all are modified. That's what the documentation
>   means by "object or objects". Singular if wait-any, plural if
>   wait-all.